# jquery .live('change') bringing back dodgy results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple dropdown boxes on my page, what i'm trying to do is get the value of the one that has been changed, when it is changed. But what's happening is that I only get the value of the first dropdown box that was added.

this is how they are added:

```
$(".payCell1").each(function(i, data)
{
    $(this).html("<select id='selection"+i+"' class='selectoror' style='width:167px'><option></option><option>Energy Efficient Lighting Systems</option><option>Lighting and Associated Systems</option><option>Efficient Lighting in Poultry & Green houses</option><option>Advanced Lighting Technologies</option><option>Building Management Systems</option><option>Sensors and Controls</option><option>HVAC Systems</option><option>Electrical Hot Water Systems</option><option>Heatpumps</option><option>Induction Heating</option><option>Showerheads and Temperature Control</option><option>Process optimisation</option><option>Compressed Air Systems / Hydraulics</option><option>Process Heating</option><option>Refrigeration and Cooling</option><option>Waste Heat Recovery (Incl Micro Turbines)</option><option>Electric Boilers and Steam Systems</option><option>Drying Technologies</option><option>Material Handling systems -Pumps and Conveyors</option><option>Pumps</option><option>Ventilation Fans</option><option>Energy Efficient Motor Systems</option><option>Advanced Motor Technologies (VSDs etc.)</option><option>Thermal Insulation (cooling & Heating)</option><option>Agriculture Irrigation Systems</option><option>Ind & Com Solar Hot Water Systems</option></select>") 
});
```

And this is the code that i use to try and get the values:

```
$(".selectoror").live('change', function()
{
    var parental = $(this).closest(".payTableRow");
    var childrens = $(parental).find(".container");

    alert($(this+":selected").val());

    if($(this+":selected").val() != "Ind & Com Solar Hot Water Systems")
    {
        $(childrens[1]).html("42");
    }
    else
    {
        $(childrens[1]).html("70");
    }
});
```

but no matter which dropdown's selection is changed I change it only returns the first ones value.

here's the html:

```
       <form id="form">
            <div style="background:url(images/top_menu2.jpg) no-repeat; width: 966px; height: 49px;"></div>
            <div class="payTableRow"><div class="payCell1 container"></div><div class="payCell2 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell3 container"><div data-pay-edit="no">0</div></div><div class="payCell4 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell5 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell6 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell7 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell8 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell9 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell10 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell11 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell12 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div></div>
            <div class="payTableRow"><div class="payCell1 container"></div><div class="payCell2 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell3 container"><div data-pay-edit="no">0</div></div><div class="payCell4 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell5 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell6 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell7 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell8 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell9 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell10 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell11 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell12 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div></div>
            <div class="payTableRow"><div class="payCell1 container"></div><div class="payCell2 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell3 container"><div data-pay-edit="no">0</div></div><div class="payCell4 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell5 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell6 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell7 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell8 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell9 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell10 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell11 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell12 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div></div>
            <div class="payTableRow"><div class="payCell1 container"></div><div class="payCell2 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell3 container"><div data-pay-edit="no">0</div></div><div class="payCell4 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell5 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell6 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell7 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell8 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell9 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell10 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell11 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell12 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div></div>
            <div class="payTableRow"><div class="payCell1 container"></div><div class="payCell2 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell3 container"><div data-pay-edit="no">0</div></div><div class="payCell4 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell5 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell6 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell7 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell8 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell9 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell10 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell11 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell12 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div></div>
            <div class="payTableRow"><div class="payCell1 container"></div><div class="payCell2 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell3 container"><div data-pay-edit="no">0</div></div><div class="payCell4 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell5 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell6 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell7 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell8 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell9 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell10 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell11 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell12 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div></div>
            <div class="payTableRow"><div class="payCell1 container"></div><div class="payCell2 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell3 container"><div data-pay-edit="no">0</div></div><div class="payCell4 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell5 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell6 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell7 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell8 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell9 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell10 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell11 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell12 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div></div>
            <div class="payTableRow"><div class="payCell1 container"></div><div class="payCell2 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell3 container"><div data-pay-edit="no">0</div></div><div class="payCell4 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell5 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell6 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell7 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell8 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell9 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell10 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell11 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div><div class="payCell12 container"><div data-pay-edit="yes">0</div></div></div>
    </form>
```

any help much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you post your HTML or make a jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `:selected` (and doing `$(this+":selected")` is a very bad idea, one is a javascript/dom object and the other a string, their concatenation is not what you're looking for), so try just

```
$(".selectoror").live('change', function() {
    ...
    alert($(this).val());
    ...
});
```

This shows that you don't need the `:selected` selector: http://jsfiddle.net/NJyH2/

And this is your code working: http://jsfiddle.net/NJyH2/1/